# Use ActionMailer to send emails through Mandrill API, not SMTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mandrill

Currently, We are using Mandrill SMTP to send emails with ActionMailer, but we are interested in switch it to the Mandrill HTTP API. Our interest is to have more control over the response, as we are not able to get the mandrill message id using the SMTP protocol.

However, it seems like there is no a gem to provide an smooth integration to use Mandril API as an ActionMailer delivery method.

Action mailer has this config setting:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Is there any gem to use mandrill http api as delivery method?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good explanation of how to add a custom delivery method for mandrill:

http://www.alanverga.com/blog/2014/01/03/custom-rails-mailer-and-mandrill

First you create a class that handles the delivery using the api, then on an initializer:

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :mandrill_delivery, MandrillDelivery
```

And on your environment config file you set your delivery method.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mandrill_delivery
```